# Is there any way to create APIs on jsfiddle and call the same via JS fiddle code?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, fiddle

We want to build a full-stack solution on js fiddle and don't want to use any IDE.

1. One way is to create a frontend on https://jsfiddle.net/ and backend on https://www.mockable.io/ . We will be able to call the hosted APIs on mockable.io from jsfiddle but the problem is we want to demonstrate with code how an API is created and mockable.io just gives you an endpoint that returns the JSON.
2. Is there any way by which we can create an API from scratch on JS fiddle or a similar tool. We are planning to use MERN stack.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way by which we can create an API from scratch on JS fiddle

No. JSFiddle only supports client-side code. It has some limited ability to [echo data back](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests) for the purposes of testing code that makes HTTP requests, but that is not sufficient to create an API.